# The Maven Command With spring-boot:spring-image Doesn't Work As What It Should Do

Tags: spring-boot

For a spring boot 2.3 project, I run

```
./mvnw spring-boot:build-image
```

and it yields the same outcome as

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

which run the application, but doesn't create a Docker image.

For its sister project with the same set of dependencies, the command works properly.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please add more logs

Comment: @PatrickChen Do you mean those messages on the console? If so, I see the same output messages as spring-boot:run.

Comment: yeah. There are so many reasons to cause the spring-boot plugin not working, without the error msg, how do we help you

Comment: I don't see any error messages. I will post the output soon.

Comment: try to open the debug mode `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
`

Comment: Thanks. I run the same command inside Intellij Idea and get a different result. I guess that my Docker environment was messed up somehow in the command line. And I run the same command in the command line and get the right result. My dev environment is Linux.